# bt-hybrid, iso-hybrid, webboot; What is the difference?

Tags: linux, variants

I recently had to pick a Linux distribution to download from a website.
I was confronted with three choices; a bt-hybrid version, a iso-hybrid version and a webboot version. What are the differences?

Answer (score 7):

**bt** - only bit torrent file for download .iso file

**iso** - only .iso file

**webboot** - I don't know,
:    but probably with pxe or something to install iso via the internet ( for server )
Have a look at the [Live Systems Manual](http://debian-live.alioth.debian.org/live-manual/stable/manual/html/live-manual.en.html)

**hybrid** - specially prepared .iso file for boot usb pendrive ( flash drives )
You can find out more here: [Isohybrid](http://syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Isohybrid)
and here [Ubuntu switched to Hybrid Disc Images](http://tuxgarage.com/2011/06/ubuntu-switched-to-hybrid-disc-images.html)